# Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-select

How do I get the selected value from a dropdown list using JavaScript?

```html
<form>
  <select id="ddlViewBy">
    <option value="1">test1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">test2</option>
    <option value="3">test3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3772, accepted):

Given a select element that looks like this:

```html
<select id="ddlViewBy">
  <option value="1">test1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">test2</option>
  <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
```

Running this code:

```js
var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
var value = e.value;
var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

Results in:

```
value == 2
text == "test2"
```

---

Interactive example:

```js
var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
function onChange() {
  var value = e.value;
  var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
  console.log(value, text);
}
e.onchange = onChange;
onChange();
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="ddlViewBy">
    <option value="1">test1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">test2</option>
    <option value="3">test3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: I am writing the exactly same code BUT inside a function in script tag. When the user will select that option from the drop-down menu, then I should be getting the text. So should I be using onclick/ontoggle/onchange ?Which of the one ?

Comment: `var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;` why not just `var strUser = e.value ?`

Comment: @TheRedPea—perhaps because when this answer was written there was a chance (however remote) that an ancient version of Netscape Navigator needed to be accommodated, so an equally ancient method for accessing the value of a single select was used. But I'm just guessing about that. ;-)

Comment: I used like this: `var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy").value;`

Comment: @RishiDua you can iterate the options of the select: `for(var o of e.options) { if (o.selected) { /* ... */ } }`

Comment: Good answer but this doesn't work well for a  multi select. Can someone assist?

Comment: @Harold_Finch for(var o of e.options) { if (o.selected) { /* ... */ } } solution should work, although I dont remember what I did (2yr old comment).

Comment: should be `e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text` don't know why it's wrong in all answers here..

Comment: `e.val()` was enough for me

Comment: Purists would even write `const e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");` since it will not change (it's a DOM assumption)

Comment: @OZZIE - Look at the assignment statement beginning with `var e` in the OP's question. While it's convention for `e` (or `event`) to represent the `eventObject`, here the OP is using it to represent the element.

Comment: @Salam That's jQuery, not plain JavaScript.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_htmlselectelement_selectedindex says `selectedIndex` is also unsupported on ancient android browsers (2.1-4.3)

Answer (score 476):

Plain JavaScript:

```
var e = document.getElementById("elementId");
var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

jQuery:

```
$("#elementId :selected").text(); // The text content of the selected option
$("#elementId").val(); // The value of the selected option
```

[AngularJS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS): (http://jsfiddle.net/qk5wwyct):

```
// HTML
<select ng-model="selectItem" ng-options="item as item.text for item in items">
</select>
<p>Text: {{selectItem.text}}</p>
<p>Value: {{selectItem.value}}</p>

// JavaScript
$scope.items = [{
  value: 'item_1_id',
  text: 'Item 1'
}, {
  value: 'item_2_id',
  text: 'Item 2'
}];
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong because when I try this I get back the text of every option in the drop down.

Comment: This did worked for me in different way. $("#ddlViewBy :selected").val() not without selected

Comment: `element.options[e.selectedIndex].value` must be `element.options[element.selectedIndex].value`

Comment: Still useful - thank you for writing out the variations / language! Now if I only knew the equivalent for Office JS API Dropdown...

Comment: should be `e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text` don't know why it's wrong in all answers here..

Comment: It also worked for me in jQuery by simply putting `$("#elementId").val()` with no need to mention the `selected`

Answer (score 197):

```
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

This is correct and should give you the value.
Is it the text you're after?

```
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

So you're clear on the terminology:

```
<select>
    <option value="hello">Hello World</option>
</select>
```

This option has:

- Index = 0
- Value = hello
- Text = Hello World

Comment: i thought the ".value" in javascript should returns the value for me but only the ".text" would returns as what the .SelectedValue in asp.net returns. Thanks for example given!

Comment: Yep - make the value of the option the same as what it is.  Simpler - the guy above needs to write more code to make up for his initial vagueness.

Comment: should be `e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text` don't know why it's wrong in all answers here..

Comment: I create modals using this code: 
<script src="https://jsuites.net/v5/jsuites.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jsuites.net/v5/jsuites.css" type="text/css" />

<div id="dropdown"></div>

<script>
  jSuites.dropdown(document.getElementById('dropdown'), {
    data: [
      {group: 'Breads', value: '1', text: 'Wholemeal'},
      {group: 'Breakfast Cereals', value: '4', text: 'Porridge'},
      {group: 'Grains', value: '5', text: 'Rice'},
      {group: 'Other products', value: '6', text: 'Pasta'},
    ],
    width: '280px',
    autocomplete: true,
  });
</script>

Answer (score 72):

The following code exhibits various examples related to getting/putting of values from input/select fields using JavaScript.

**[Source Link](http://www.freakyjolly.com/how-to-get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-jquery-javascript/)**

Working [**Javascript & jQuery Demo**](https://freakyjolly.com/demo/getDropDownValue_JavaScript_jQuery.html)

[image]

[image]

```
 <select id="Ultra" onchange="run()">  <!--Call run() function-->
     <option value="0">Select</option>
     <option value="8">text1</option>
     <option value="5">text2</option>
     <option value="4">text3</option>
</select><br><br>
TextBox1<br>
<input type="text" id="srt" placeholder="get value on option select"><br>
TextBox2<br>
<input type="text" id="rtt"  placeholder="Write Something !" onkeyup="up()">
```

**The following script is getting the value of the selected option and putting it in text box 1**

```
<script>
    function run() {
        document.getElementById("srt").value = document.getElementById("Ultra").value;
    }
</script>
```

**The following script is getting a value from a text box 2 and alerting with its value**

```
<script>
    function up() {
        //if (document.getElementById("srt").value != "") {
            var dop = document.getElementById("srt").value;
        //}
        alert(dop);
    }
</script>
```

**The following script is calling a function from a function**

```
<script>
    function up() {
        var dop = document.getElementById("srt").value;
        pop(dop); // Calling function pop
    }

    function pop(val) {
        alert(val);
    }?
</script>
```

Comment: `onchange=run(this.value)` or `(this.text)` can be more benefficial.

Answer (score 55):

```
var selectedValue = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy").value;
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution, at least for modern browsers. See also [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_value.asp).

Answer (score 27):

If you ever run across code written purely for Internet Explorer you might see this:

```
var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
var strUser = e.options(e.selectedIndex).value;
```

Running the above in Firefox et al will give you an 'is not a function' error, because Internet Explorer  allows you to get away with using () instead of []:

```
var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

The correct way is to use square brackets.

Answer (score 22):

Use:

```html
<select id="Ultra" onchange="alert(this.value)">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="8">text1</option>
    <option value="5">text2</option>
    <option value="4">text3</option>
</select>
```

Any input/form field can use a “this” keyword when you are  accessing it from inside the element. This eliminates the need for locating a form in the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) tree and then locating this element inside the form.

Answer (score 19):

There are two ways to get this done either using JavaScript or jQuery.

**JavaScript:**

```
var getValue = document.getElementById('ddlViewBy').selectedOptions[0].value;

alert (getValue); // This will output the value selected.
```

**OR**

```
var ddlViewBy = document.getElementById('ddlViewBy');

var value = ddlViewBy.options[ddlViewBy.selectedIndex].value;

var text = ddlViewBy.options[ddlViewBy.selectedIndex].text;

alert (value); // This will output the value selected

alert (text); // This will output the text of the value selected
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#ddlViewBy:selected").text(); // Text of the selected value

$("#ddlViewBy").val(); // Outputs the value of the ID in 'ddlViewBy'
```

Answer (score 18):

Beginners are likely to want to access values from a select with the NAME attribute rather than ID attribute. We know all form elements need names, even before they get ids.

So, I'm adding the `getElementsByName()` solution just for new developers to see too.

NB. names for form elements will need to be unique for your form to be usable once posted, but the DOM can allow a name be shared by more than one element. For that reason consider adding IDs to forms if you can, or be explicit with form element names `my_nth_select_named_x` and `my_nth_text_input_named_y`.

Example using `getElementsByName`:

```
var e = document.getElementsByName("my_select_with_name_ddlViewBy")[0];
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: Doesn't work if my_select_with_name_ddlViewBy is an array like my_select_with_name_ddlViewBy[]

Answer (score 15):

Just use

- `$('#SelectBoxId option:selected').text();` for getting the text as listed
- `$('#SelectBoxId').val();` for getting the selected index value

Comment: This uses jQuery, which doesn't answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure if I totally understand your question, but this worked for me:

Use an onchange() event in your HTML, for example.

```html
<select id="numberToSelect" onchange="selectNum()">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

#### JavaScript

```javascript
function selectNum() {
    var strUser = document.getElementById("numberToSelect").value;
}
```

This will give you whatever value is on the select dropdown per click.

Answer (score 9):

The previous answers still leave room for improvement because of the possibilities, the intuitiveness of the code, and the use of `id` versus `name`. One can get a read-out of three data of a selected option -- its index number, its value and its text. This simple, cross-browser code does all three:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo GetSelectOptionData</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="demoForm">
        <select name="demoSelect" onchange="showData()">
            <option value="zilch">Select:</option>
            <option value="A">Option 1</option>
            <option value="B">Option 2</option>
            <option value="C">Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </form>

    <p id="firstP">&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="secondP">&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="thirdP">&nbsp;</p>

    <script>
        function showData() {
            var theSelect = demoForm.demoSelect;
            var firstP = document.getElementById('firstP');
            var secondP = document.getElementById('secondP');
            var thirdP = document.getElementById('thirdP');
            firstP.innerHTML = ('This option\'s index number is: ' + theSelect.selectedIndex + ' (Javascript index numbers start at 0)');
            secondP.innerHTML = ('Its value is: ' + theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].value);
            thirdP.innerHTML = ('Its text is: ' + theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].text);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Live demo: http://jsbin.com/jiwena/1/edit?html,output .

`id` should be used for make-up purposes. For functional form purposes, `name` is still valid, also in HTML5, and should still be used. Lastly, mind the use of square versus round brackets in certain places. As was explained before, only (older versions of) Internet Explorer will accept round ones in all places.

Answer (score 9):

Using jQuery:

```
$('select').val();
```

Answer (score 8):

Another solution is:

```
document.getElementById('elementId').selectedOptions[0].value
```

Comment: It is [**not cross-browser compatible**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13753201/9801830).

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way to do this is:

```
var value = document.getElementById("selectId").value;
```

Comment: He wants not the value but the shown text of the select box

Comment: I think this is the actual answer most people are looking for.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `querySelector`.

**E.g.**

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('ddlViewBy');

var myValue = myElement.querySelector('[selected]').value;
```

Answer (score 7):

Most answers here get the value of the "this" select menu `onchange` by a plain text JavaScript selector.

For example:

```
document.getElementById("ddlViewBy").value;
```

This is **not** a [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) approach.

### DRY (three lines of code):

```
function handleChange(e) {
  let innerText = e.target[e.target.options.selectedIndex].innerText;
  let value = e.target.value;
  /* Do something with these values */
}
```

Get the first select option:

```
console.log(e.target[0]); /* Output: <option value="value_hello">Hello innerText</option>*/
```

With this idea in mind, we dynamically return a "this" select option item (by `selectedIndex`):

```
e.target[e.target.options.selectedIndex].innerText;
```

#### Demo

```js
let log = document.getElementById('log');

function handleChange(e) {
  let innerText = e.target[e.target.options.selectedIndex].innerText;
  let value = e.target.value;

  log.innerHTML = `<table>
    <tr><th>value</th><th>innerText</th></tr>
    <tr><td>${value}</td><td>${innerText}</td></tr>
  </table>`;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/milligram/1.4.1/milligram.css">

<select id="greet" onchange="handleChange(event)">
  <option value="value_hello">Hello innerText</option>
  <option value="value_goodbye">Goodbye innerText</option>
  <option value="value_seeYou">See you... innerText</option>
</select>

<select id="other_select_menu" onchange="handleChange(event)">
  <option value="value_paris">Paris innerText</option>
  <option value="value_ny">New York innerText</option>
</select>

<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: there's DRY and there's verbosity to make your code easier to understand. I feel this answer adds complexity on multiple levels in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Running example of how it works:

```js
var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
var val1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var txt = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

document.write("<br />Selected option Value: "+ val1);
document.write("<br />Selected option Text: "+ txt);
```

```html
<select id="ddlViewBy">
  <option value="1">test1</option>
  <option value="2">test2</option>
  <option value="3"  selected="selected">test3</option>
</select>
```

Note: The values don't change as the dropdown is changed, if you require that functionality then an onClick change is to be implemented.

Comment: Good answer for showing how the code needs to be refreshed after used!

Answer (score 5):

To go along with the previous answers, this is how I do it as a one-liner. This is for getting the actual text of the selected option. There are good examples for getting the index number already. (And for the text, I just wanted to show this way)

```
let selText = document.getElementById('elementId').options[document.getElementById('elementId').selectedIndex].text
```

In some rare instances you may need to use parentheses, but this would be very rare.

```
let selText = (document.getElementById('elementId')).options[(document.getElementById('elementId')).selectedIndex].text;
```

I doubt this processes any faster than the two line version. I simply like to consolidate my code as much as possible.

Unfortunately this still fetches the element twice, which is not ideal. A method that only grabs the element once would be more useful, but I have not figured that out yet, in regards to doing this with one line of code.

Answer (score 5):

I have a bit different view of how to achieve this. I'm usually doing this with the following approach (it is an easier way and works with every browser as far as I know):

```html
<select onChange="functionToCall(this.value);" id="ddlViewBy">
  <option value="value1">Text one</option>
  <option value="value2">Text two</option>
  <option value="value3">Text three</option>
  <option value="valueN">Text N</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

In more modern browsers, `querySelector` allows us to retrieve the selected option in one statement, using the [`:checked` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked). From the selected option, we can gather whatever information we need:

```js
const opt = document.querySelector('#ddlViewBy option:checked');
// opt is now the selected option, so
console.log(opt.value, 'is the selected value');
console.log(opt.text, "is the selected option's text");
```

```html
<select id="ddlViewBy">
  <option value="1">test1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">test2</option>
  <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

In 2015, in [Firefox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox), the following also works.

> e.**options**.selectedIndex

Answer (score 4):

I think you can attach an event listener to the select tag itself e.g:

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (_) => {
    document.querySelector("select").addEventListener("change", (e) => {
      console.log(e.target.value);
    });
  });
</script>
```

In this scenario, you should make sure you have a value attribute for all of your options, and they are not null.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! In my case, I have two selectors, but I was able to access the selector id with 'e.srcElement.id'

Answer (score 4):

`event.target.value` inside the onChange callback did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a JavaScript code line:

```
var x = document.form1.list.value;
```

Assuming that the dropdown menu named list `name="list"` and included in a form with name attribute `name="form1"`.

Comment: OP said that didn't work for them: "I tried the methods below but they all return the selected index instead of the value:
`var as = document.form1.ddlViewBy.value;`..."

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `querySelector` to achieve this. This also standardizes the way of getting a value from form elements.

`var dropDownValue = document.querySelector('#ddlViewBy').value;`

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3t80pubr/

Answer (score 3):

```
<select name="test" id="test" >
    <option value="1" full-name="Apple">A</option>
    <option value="2" full-name="Ball">B</option>
    <option value="3" full-name="Cat" selected>C</option>
</select>

var obj  = document.getElementById('test');
obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;  //3
obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;   //C
obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].getAttribute('full-name'); //Cat
obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].selected; //true
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
ddlViewBy.value                      // value

ddlViewBy.selectedOptions[0].text    // label
```

```js
console.log( ddlViewBy.value );

console.log( ddlViewBy.selectedOptions[0].text );
```

```html
<select id="ddlViewBy">
  <option value="1">Happy</option>
  <option value="2">Tree</option>
  <option value="3"  selected="selected">Friends</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy way to do it in an onchange function:

`event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].dataset.name`

Comment: Talking about simplicity, I was thinking about **this** instead of **event.target**

Answer (score 0):

Just do: `document.getElementById('idselect').options.selectedIndex`

Then you’ll get the select index value, starting at 0.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround, using the [EasyUI](http://jeasyui.com/) framework with all of its [plugins](http://jeasyui.com/documentation/index.php#).

You only need to add some EasyUI object that can read from an input as a "bridge" to the drop-down menu.

Example: easyui-searchbox

To the left, the drop-down, to the right, the easyui-searchbox:

[image]

```html
...
<input id="ss" class="easyui-searchbox" style="width:300px"
        data-options="  searcher:my_function,
                        prompt:'Enter value',
                        menu:'#mm'">
<div id="mm" style="width:200px">
    <div data-options="name:'1'">test1</div>
    <div data-options="name:'2'">test2</div>
</div>
...
```

```js
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    function my_js_function(triggeredByButton = false){
        // normal text of the searchbox (what you entered)
        var value = $("#ss").searchbox("getValue");
        // what you chose from the drop-down menu
        var name = $("#ss").searchbox("getName");
...
```

Mind: the `var name` is the '1' or '2', that is, the "value of the drop-down", while `var value` is the value that was entered in the easyui-searchbox instead and not relevant if you only want to know the value of the drop-down.

I checked how EasyUI fetches that `#mm` name, and I could not find out how to get that name without the help of EasyUI. The jQuery behind `getName`:

```js
getName:function(jq){
return $.data(jq[0],"searchbox").searchbox.find("input.textbox-value").attr("name");
}
```

Mind that the return of this function is not the value of the easyui-searchbox, but the name of the `#mm` drop-down that was used as the `menu` parameter of the easyui-searchbox. Somehow EasyUI must get that other value, therefore it must be possible.

If you do not want any plugin to be seen, make it as tiny as possible? Or find perhaps a plugin that does not need a form at all in the link above, I just did not take the time.